# Create column using web services API

Tags: 2010, document-library, web-services

In Sharepoint 2010, is there a way to create a new column for a Document Library using the web services API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the UpdateList method of the Lists.asmx web service.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelist(v=office.12).aspx for more details (this is from 2007, but still works in 2010).

You will basically use XML to add/remove columns using the Field schema.  There is a code example on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Is using the web service a requirement?
Otherwise, you can use the SharePoint CSOM to add a field to a list:

example in javascript:

```
function addFieldToList() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');
this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'MyField\' Type=\'Number\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);

var fieldNumber = clientContext.castTo(oField,SP.FieldNumber);    
fieldNumber.update();

clientContext.load(oField);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

}

Refer to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185005%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more info about the javascript CSOM or to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for the .NET version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The requirement is to make the call from a Java application so using the web service appears be best.